# "Present" vs "future tense" in subordinate clauses in this context

Tags: grammar, spoken-english, subordinate-clauses

A conversation between two friends:

> A: When will you come to our house.
>
> B: I will go **when my mother goes / when my mother will go.**

I know that we are supposed to use only the **present tense** in **subordinate clauses.** But here **when my mother goes** doesn't sound nice to my ear although I'm a mere learner.

How would **native speakers** say this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I will go when my mother goes" is perfectly normal, except that most people would say "I'll go" rather than "I will go". There is nothing odd about "when my mother goes".

Comment: This app really gives me the feeling of living around English speakers.

Comment: Most English speakers would probably respond **I'll come when my mother comes** because the question is **when will you come...**. This has nothing to do with grammar, just with idiomatic speech.